# How can I add some probable Keywords to hashcat, so I can Brute-Force attack a WPA2 Network faster

Tags: wifi, brute-force, wpa2, hashcat

I´m trying to brute force attack a WPA2 Network with Hashcat and a wpa2.hccpax file, but when I do it says that it can take 45years to brute force it. So I had the idea that probably the network I´m trying to brute force has 2 probable words that the password may include, but I don't know where or the order of them. I´ve searched and I found a Hybrid attack mode for Hashcat, but it has a problem, I can only put on the final or on the beginning, and I don´t think this network would start with these words or ends with these words, it would be too obvious.

So, is there any way I can specify these words to hashcat so when is bruteforcing it will try to bruteforce with those words in any order and some alphanumeric characters (both uppercase and lowercase) to complete it? Also, can I add something that says the password lenght may range between 8 to 18 characters?

Note:These 2 words would also include variations like, first letter uppercase and the others lowercase, or all uppercase and so on.

Comment: Have you read [how to use masks in hashcat](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack)?

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't see it. But I'm not understanding how I put the keyspace in the command and how do I say to hashcat to try this in a range of 8 to 18.

Comment: They do provide examples. I suggest to read it and try it out and adapt.

Comment: So, I´ve read this documentation and and as I can understand, in a Mask Attack I can actually define to hashcat to try the word I want and then some alphanumeric characters before or after the specified word. But the thing is, these words could be positioned anywhere on the password, so I would actually need to make lots of trial and error. Then, I also thinked that maybe creating a charset file and put all of alphanumeric characters and the words I want in there, but,  first, how could I create one of these and 2, wouldn´t the word be separated in characters and then it wouldn´t metter?

Comment: What I´m saying with "it wouldn´t metter" is, wouldn´t the word be separated into individual characters?